# Reading and displaying large formatted text documents in Android

Tags: java, c#, android, text, xamarin

I'm developing an Android app which is supposed to present large text files (books for example), for the user to browse, read, and search.

My question is as follows:
How should I read and present the text file, which is currently in either a PDF or Word format, and is formatted?

What file should the text be in (.doc, .txt, .xml, .html)?

What controls/elements and code should I use to read it on the app so that it should be presented efficiently and formatted correctly (TextView, WebView, PDF reader, or some other way)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your application and programming skills,

1. Grabbing texts from PDFs, word files, etc.. can be done using 
   libraries (lots are available)
2. you can save your files as raw text files (they could be readable
   manually) if you want to want to secure it you can encrypt it before
   saving and you can save with custom extension( *.lib,*.abc etc..).
3. TextViews are the easiest as you can change the colors ,
   fonts and text size, it's really fast and easy to deal with.

Edit : example of reading a text file

```
        File myFile = new File("/sdcard/filename.txt");
        FileInputStream iStr = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStr ));
        String TextLine= "";
        String TextBuffer = "";
        while ((TextLine= fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            TextBuffer += TextLine+ "\n";
        }
        textView1.setText(TextBuffer );
        fileReader.close();
```

example of writing a text file :

```
        File myFile = new File("/sdcard/filename.txt");
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream oStr = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter fileWriter= new OutputStreamWriter(oStr);
        fileWriter.append(textView1.getText());
        fileWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what way is most accepted and widely used, and how do I read it from code?

Comment: These libraries are for desktop apps but it may work on Xamarin (worth a try) [read text libraries](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/reading-contents-from-pdf-word-text-files-in-c-sharp1)

Comment: I couldn't get iTextSharp to work on Xamarin. Any other suggestions? What is accepted in Android in general in these cases? Should I parse a text file, convert it to xml, html, or something else?

Comment: I think you have to use many libraries for different files extensions ,,what types of files are you trying to parse ?

Comment: I have documents which I can choose which format they will be in- doc, pdf, xml, html, txt, etc. I'm trying to figure out the best way to parse them and the best file extension for this purpose.

Comment: text file don't need libraries actually ,, i will add some code to the answer to read text files from sd card ,, you may have to pick your own "path" by Intent that picks files or by any other way

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for. The files are formatted more than just new lines- numbers, letters, titles, subtitles, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112080/discussion-between-ayad-kara-kahya-and-amitairos).